# Render in 4.0 very long

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been working on a scene in Blender 3.6 and it takes 1 min to render. When I open the same scene in Blender 4.0, it is long and estimate the render of the frame to 44 hours.
I use Cycle.
And I saw that the device : GPU Compute is greyed out.

Any help would be welcomed.
Cheers
Lucas :)

Comment: A greyed out GPU means you haven't selected a GPU in Blender's system preferences tab.

Comment: Selecting a GPU in preference tab made it work perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! <3